# update script for BLOB column in ORACLE needs to be created

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, procedure

I want to create update script for BLOB column in Table which stores XSL Data in ORACLE.  Can anybody help me in simple way without creating any directory.  Here number of character involved is also more than 4000.
I have modified in TOAD by 'Save to File' and again from 'Load to File'.  Now I want to transfer it to some other database using SQL Script.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Oracle IMP and EXP utilities you can export a table into a file and import it into another database. Here is some information on how to use them:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

It is not SQL but it also doesn't involve creating directories.

Comment: Whether there is any other method by creating update script instead of using IMP and EXP utility